# How to use HTML, Database & JS to create a filter function

Tags: javascript, html, database

I am an entry level learner for HTML, JS and database. Currently, I am using HTML & JS & DB to create a student information tracking webpage which enable admin office to input and track student information record. After user input and submit information, the record will save to database fact table and will also display in the summary table on the homepage. 
On the data input page there is a dropdown list for supervisor which will extract supervisor data from database:

```
    <label for ="supervisor">Supervisor</label>
    <select name="supervisor" id="supervisor"><option>Supervisor</option></select >
```

The supervisor table in the database is :

```
 supervisorKey            supervisorLabel             SupervisorOrder
      1             Alex Grey(email1@gmail.com)           1
      2             Carol Hann(email2@gmail.com)            2  
      ...                ...                               ...
      20            Not Selected                            0
```

Now I am creating a filter function for the summary table. After click filter button, a new page which include different options will show up. One of the filter options is search student record based on the supervisor's name or supervisor's school. For each supervisor belong to one of the three schools (business, engineering, art).

The user wants the "supervisor dropdown list" to look like below in the filter tool, which means the user can either search by choosing the specific school to see all the students who be supervised by all the professors from that school or search by choosing the professor's name:

```
supervisor:
     Engineering School
     Business School
     Art School
     Alex Grey
     Carol Hann
      ....
     Not Selected
```

I tried to create new table "school", and add school key to the "supervisor table"

```
schoolKey           schoolLabel     schoolOrder
1                Engineering School    1
2                 Business School      2
3                    Art School        3
```

The filter function doesn't work, and I don't know how to put school's and supervisor's name under the same dropdown list.

Comment: can you explain in detail about the purpose of 'filter function'? At first glance, I think you can filter by query statements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching data from database and displaying in a tabular format in html, then you can make use of datatables which automatically add search and sort facility to table.
check here : datatables.net